# Не могу передать переменную из метода класса, в другой класс

Tags: java

```
package com.company;

public class LoginForm implements ActionListener {
JButton button;
JTextField yourLogin;
JTextField result;
String login = null;

public void log() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    yourLogin = new JTextField();
    result = new JTextField();
    button = new JButton("Login");
    button.addActionListener(this);//
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, button);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, yourLogin);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, result);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
} // Создает фрейм с кнопкой и текстовыми полями, в котором при нажатии кнопки значение из поля передается в String login
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
  login = yourLogin.getText();
    result.setText(login);
    System.out.println(login); // Работает, выдает результат в консоль 

    }
    public String getLogin(){ 
    return login;
} // Геттер, нужно чтобы так же передавал результат в консоль. Но он передает null. То есть использует переменную класса а не метода 
}
```

MAIN

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    LoginForm logg = new LoginForm();
logg.log();
   System.out.println(logg.getLogin()); // Выдает null. Берет переменную класса а не метода
   }

}
```

Comment: Вам надо по нажатии кнопки событие отрабатывать?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут дело в ассинхронности кода. Вы инициализируете `LoginForm` далее метод `.log()` у вас, можно сказать, выступает в качестве конструктора:

- инициализирует переменные.
- вешает событие на кнопку.

Далее у вас сразу же вызывается `.getLogin()`. А ведь `login` еще null, на сколько мы помним.

И только после клика на кнопку, `login` получает значение из нашего поля для логина.

Вобщем, чтобы решить Вашу проблему, нужно знать конкретно что Вы пытаетесь получить и куда передать

Comment: Необходимо из textField по нажатию кнопки вытянуть введенную информацию и призвоить ее переменной login. Далее необходимо с login работать в других классах, которые могут например вносить информацию в БД, или вносить значение в массив. Не получается именно вытянуть данную переменную из метода. Сеичас конкретно хочу передать ее в Main.

Comment: Да вы правы, добавил в get Thread.sleep(5000); Теперь если за 5 секунд успеть нажать кнопку, то все сработает верно. Но это мегатупой костыль. Буду думать либо над дополнительным ивентом, либо как отказаться от Гета, либо над костылем поэлегантнее.

Comment: Можно же при нажатии на кнопку вызывать метод другого класса, который бы записывал логин в БД. Просто не нужно получать login не в то время не в том месте :) Вся проблема именно в этом.

Comment: На примере андроидов могу сказать такой подход:
создаем активити с формой логина. Человек нажимает на кнопку, ждем пока сервер обработает нашу форму. Если всё ок, то закрываем активити с формой логина и переходим а основному экрану.
Надеюсь это Вам поможет

Answer (score 1):

Переменная `login` не инициализируется в конструкторе и методе `log()`, поэтому `null` и возвращает